# PrimeNg: How to create a new instance of the items in a dialog when the dialog is shown

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the primeNg dialog in an Angular2 app, like this:

```
<p-dialog 
    header="Dialog" 
    [(visible)]="display"
    [modal]=true
    [closable]=true
    [resizable]=false
    [width]=500
    >
        <input type="text"/>
    </p-dialog>
```

Now suppose that I do the following:

- Launch the dialog
- Type `Led Zeppelin` into the dialog
- Close the dialog
- Reopen the dialog

Now the input is still populated with `Led Zeppelin`.

I understand that the same instance of the input is being used, but this is not the behavior that I want.  I would like the dialog to use a new input each time it is launched.  What is the right way to do this?  One way to approach this could be to use the `onBeforeShow` to reset the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not necessary to attach to a specific life-cycle hook. I assume that you are using a button to display the dialog, to that button you could attach a method or a `javascript` sentence like this:

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="newName='';displayDialog();"></button>
```

and your input looks like:

```
<input id="myId" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="newName"/>
```

Where `newName=''` is a variable of type `string` that you are cleaning before displaying the dialog and `pInputText` is a `primeng` directive: [link](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputtext)

No matter if you are not using a button to trigger the dialog, I think you got the idea.